# How to secure and enrypt android app data

Tags: android, encryption, ssl-certificate, postdata

I want to pass android app data securely on Server. SSL certificate is installed on server but still want to add one more layer over it.

What is the best way to secure and encrypt the android app data?

What other checks should be added on server/app  to protect data?

Comment: SSL secures communication between Server and Android App. Which part you want to secure more, communication between server and app or data stored in Android App? From which Kind of Attach you want to secure ?

Comment: There is no point in encrypting during transit if you already have a (valid) TLS setup - it's the definition of superfluous.

Comment: @logonmanish: I want to secure Communication between server and app.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark : Just want to add another layer of security to protect data.

Comment: Adding "another layer of security" through whatever homebrew concoction of naive cryptography you come up with is akin to gluing a piece of paper onto a 6 foot thick concrete wall for "extra security".